# Issue with in-app update implementation on Android 13 Go without Google Play Services

Tags: android, in-app-update, packageinstaller, android-go

I'm working on an IoT smart module that runs on Android 13 Go, and it doesn't have Google Play Services. I am trying to implement an in-app update functionality where the app can be updated on a button click. Currently, I am able to download the APK from a URL successfully, but I'm facing issues with the installation process using the PackageInstaller. After downloading, I don't receive any response from the installApk function, and the app doesn't seem to be updated.

Code

```
    private fun downloadAndInstallApk(apkUrl: String) {
    val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(apkUrl))
        .setTitle("Sensor")
        .setDescription("Downloading")
        .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
        .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "sensor.apk")

    val downloadManager = getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
    downloadId = downloadManager.enqueue(request)

    // Register a BroadcastReceiver to listen for the download completion
    val filter = IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE)
    registerReceiver(downloadReceiver, filter)
}

private val downloadReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
    @SuppressLint("Range")
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        if (intent?.action == DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE) {
            val downloadManager = getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager

            val query = DownloadManager.Query().setFilterById(downloadId)
            val cursor = downloadManager.query(query)

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                val columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)

                if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == cursor.getInt(columnIndex)) {
                    val uri =
                        Uri.parse(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI)))

                    Log.i(TAG, "onReceive: $uri")
                    // Install the APK directly without copying to cache
                    installApk(uri)
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this@LandingActivity, "Download failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                }
            }

            cursor.close()
        }
    }
}

private fun installApk(uri: Uri) {
    Log.i(TAG, "installApk: $uri")
    val packageInstaller = packageManager.packageInstaller
    val params = PackageInstaller.SessionParams(PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL)

    val sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(params)
    val session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId)

    try {
        val inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream(uri)
        val outputStream = session.openWrite("package", 0, -1)

        inputStream.use { input ->
            outputStream.use { output ->
                input!!.copyTo(output)
            }
        }

        val intent = Intent(this, javaClass)
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
        session.commit(pendingIntent.intentSender)
    } finally {
        session.close()
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES" />

    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
```

I've implemented a downloadAndInstallApk function that successfully downloads the APK and triggers the installApk function. However, after the download, the installation doesn't seem to proceed as expected. I've used a BroadcastReceiver to listen for the download completion and initiate the installation process.

Specific Concerns:

Is there an issue with how I'm using the PackageInstaller?
Am I missing any critical steps in the installation process?
I've included the necessary permissions and a FileProvider in the manifest. Is there anything else needed for proper file access?
Additional Information:

I'm targeting Android 13 Go without Google Play Services.
I'm using a FileProvider for file access.
Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!